# flash desktop application

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

How can I remove the default menu at the top(file, view, control and debug) of my flash application when I publish my .fla file to .exe file by using window projector? Please also I am trying to add my custom menu at the top of my flash application when I published it.

I have used following code as discussed on other forums but of no use. Please help me out.

```
stage.showDefaultContextMenu = false;
```

Answer (score 4):

I don't think you can do that easy with code alone. You can work around it by putting the projector in to fullscreen mode which means you won't see it.

Alternatively as you are using Actionscript 3, why not build an AIR app which will give you the ability of removing the chrome (window border) from the application.